# Semantic search results in SQL Server does not return more than 10 rows

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017

I have set up and enabled semantic search successfully by following [this tutorial by Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/search/semantic-search-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017) in SQL Server 2017 Development Edition. The semantic search is enabled on a table `nvarchar(max)` field which retains English plain text to search them semantically. The table has 900+ rows but when I run the following SQL statement I do not receive more than 10 rows! Why am I seeing this behavior and what should I do to get more rows in the result of the statement?

```
declare @idToCompare int = 1044

SELECT TOP(50) KEY_TBL.matched_document_key AS MatchId , score 
FROM SEMANTICSIMILARITYTABLE  
    (  
    MySemanticTable,  
    ContentToSearch,  
    @idToCompare
    ) AS KEY_TBL  

ORDER BY KEY_TBL.score DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that this is an old issue that has never been addressed. This feature of SQL Server does not seem to worth utilizing unless there is a solution for that. Not sure why Microsoft introduced this feature!

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/d9bdd8d5-dec4-4076-bcb8-692f1d509c74/semanticsimilaritytable-sql2012-1102100-why-pull-max-of-only-10-results?forum=sqldatabaseengine